# How to have text displayed like a text view on watchOS

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am making an Apple Watch app for the first time.

I noticed that there was no option for a text view.  How would I get the text to be displayed as it would in a text view?  I want the string to be separated into lines so that it fits, and I want to be able to scroll if the input is long enough.

Is there a way to achieve this without a text view (or am I just not seeing the option for a text view)?

Comment: Use a `WKLabel` and set the number of lines to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a [`WKInterfaceLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/).

By setting its `numberOfLines` to 0, and height to "Size to Fit Content," the label text will scroll when it is large enough to exceed the screen size.

[image]

[image]